# Why the set $\tau$ containing finite subsets of $\mathbb Z$ and the set $\mathbb Z$ itself is not a topology on $X=\mathbb Z$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $X=\mathbb Z$ where $\mathbb Z$ in the set of integers, define a set $\tau$ on $X$ such that it contains finite subsets of $\mathbb Z$ and the the set $\mathbb Z$ itself, why $\tau$ is not a topology on $X$?

I would consider the subset of integers in the from:$$\left\{n,n+1\right\}$$ where $n$ is a non-zero integer, clearly the union of these subsets makes an infinite set, but the union of this infinite set and $\mathbb Z$ is again $\mathbb Z$ which is an element in $\tau$, I cannot understand what is the problem that makes us unable to call $\tau$ a topology.

Comment: Does your proposed topology contain the set of odd integers which can be seen as $\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^\infty \{-2n-1,2n+1\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topology must be closed under taking *arbitrary* unions.  E.g. take the union of all but two consecutive of your doubleton sets, and you get a union that is not all of $\mathbb Z$ which is infinite and not included in $\tau$.

Comment: So there are two way to be contained in the topology I defined above: either the set should be finite or the set of all integers, which in my example the set is neither the set of all integers nor a  finite subset of $\mathbb Z$

Comment: But that family of sets is *not* closed under taking arbitrary unions, so it is not a topology.  Just because we use an infinite number of finite sets does not guarantee that their union is all of the integers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider : $$2\mathbb{Z}=\cup_{i\in 2\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}}\{i\}.$$ Since $\{i\}$ is finite, $\{i\}\in\tau$. Therefore if $\tau$ is topology then by definition of topology $2\mathbb{Z}\in\tau$. However $2\mathbb{Z}\neq \mathbb{Z}$ and not finite, hence $2\mathbb{Z}\not\in \tau$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The family consisting of the finite subsets of a given (infinite) set $X$ is not a topology because it is not closed under arbitrary unions.

For instance, when $X=\mathbb N$ the set
$$
\{1,3,5,7,9,11,...\}
$$
is union of finite sets but it is neither finite, nor $\mathbb N$.

However the family satisfies the request for the **closed sets** of a topology, the so called *cofinite topology*.